# Postgres CPU utilisation shot up. Any insights for my case?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, sequelize.js

My postgres instance CPU utilisation has shot up recently. I'm trying to identify the root cause. I will add the details below.

My postgres database instance running on GCP has the following configuration:

```
v PostgreSQL 9.6
vCPUs-1
Memory-3.75 GB
SSD storage-15 GB
```

I'm running 5 databases in the above DB server which are connected with a nodejs app. 
I use sequelize as my ORM and recently upgraded my sequeliz from `4.6.x` to `5.8.6"`.

Before this upgrade the CPU utilization would usually remain less than 20 percent. But after the upgrade, I see a lot of fluctuation in CPU utilization graph. And it hits 100 percent too often as well. Also, when it hits 100%, my services start wont work as expected ( because they cant interact with the DB).

I tried running this query .

```
 SELECT "usesysid", "backend_start", "xact_start","query_start", "state_change", "state", "query" FROM pg_stat_activity ORDER BY "query_start" DESC
```

And, it returns the following:

[image: query result]
But I'm not sure if this info is enough for me to find out which query could be causing this issue.

I also ran this query:

```
SELECT max(now() - xact_start) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE state IN ('idle in transaction', 'active');
```

and it returns `max =` `1 day 01:42:10.987635`. I think this is something alarming, but i dont know how to put this info to use.

Another thing which i think is worth mentioning is, I have started using sequelize's bulk update.

Its syntax is something like this:

```
 Model.bulkCreate(scalesToUpdate, {
        updateOnDuplicate: [
            'field1',
            'field2'
        ],
    })
```

And, this gets translated into SQL like below:

```
INSERT INTO "mymodel" ("id","field1","field2","field3","field4","field5","field6","field7") VALUES (') ON CONFLICT ("id") DO UPDATE SET "field3"=EXCLUDED."field3","field4"=EXCLUDED."field4","field6"=EXCLUDED."field6","field7"=EXCLUDED."field7"
```

And, this query gets fired 5 times per second. Could this be the culprit?

Any insight into this is highly appreciable.

Comment: Use `pg_stat_statements` to find the problematic queries and tune them.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the next things:

1. Increase ht machine type to have one core more having vCPUs= 2
2. It might be that sequelize 5.8.6 requires more resources than the old version, you could try to install one of the [tools](https://www.tecmint.com/command-line-tools-to-monitor-linux-performance/) and run it, run the queries that you typed, to review which query has more resource usage.

If you have that query running 5 times per second, that could be using more resources. Test using one of the tools in order to be able to have a better approach.